# Integral of sums of basic trigonometric polynomials

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometric-series

My textbook (RCA, Rudin) asserts (in the proof of theorem 5.15) that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\lVert{\sum_{k=-n}^n}e^{ikt}\rVert_1=\infty.
$$
Why is this true?

I tried using Euler's formula to reduce the above to
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{0}^{\pi}\lvert 1+2\sum_{k=1}^n\cos(kt)\rvert~dt=\infty,
$$
but I don't know how to show that either.

Comment: Use geometric sums $$\sum_{k=-n}^ne^{ikt}=\frac{e^{i(n+1)t}-e^{-int}}{e^{it}-1}=\frac{\sin((n+1/2)t)}{\sin(1/2·t)}.$$

Comment: :facepalm: i got it now.. thank you!